# case in where clause for specific values oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

we have 2 table, table A and table B,

we are fetch 6 columns in select statement,
these are the columns

1. A.current_value,
2. A.original_value,
3. A.current_tax_lot,
4. B.current_tax,
5. B.cost_tax,
6. B.current_tax_cost

now we have to put mathematics condition in query:

1. A.current_value – B.current_tax is within +/- 2, and
2. If A.original_value is blank use A.current_tax_lot to perform the formula:

2a. A.current_tax_lot (from above) – B.cost_tax is within +/- 10, or

2b. A.current_tax_lot(from above) – current_tax_cost is within +/-10)

Comment: Homework, nice! If you run into a specific problem you can ask a question here. But don't forget to add sample table data, the expected result and your code attempt. (All as properly formatted text, no images.)

Comment: BTW, are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: should do homework by yourself though, anyway this seem like a question that can easily solve by using `case` just like your topic said...

Comment: @jarlh its oracle

Comment: @Craig query looks good but why are we not using (point b) If A.original_value is blank use A.current_tax_lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have not understood a block/calculation, substitute terms / expressions appropriately.

```
Select  ...
Where 
      ABS(NVL(A.current_value, A.current_tax_lot) – B.current_tax) <=2
      AND 
      (
         ABS(A.current_tax_lot – B.cost_tax) <= 10 
         OR
         ABS(A.current_tax_lot – B.current_tax_cost) <= 10
      );
```